# Collatz sequences meet at a point

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, collatz-conjecture

I was solving the problem,in which  we are given two starting values of **collatz sequence** and our task is to say after how many steps their sequences “meet” for the first time.
For ex - a= 7 , b= 8

a = 7 -> 22 -> 11 -> .... -> 5 -> 16 -> 8 
b = 8

So the **collatz** sequence starting with 7 will meet the other sequence at 8 .

I tried a normal approach but it's not optimized . Can anyone give good optimize approach ?

Constraints : 1<=a<=b<=10^6

Answer (score 1):

This is what I'd do. In case of many repeated queries, preparing a table "first term of Collatz sequence below starting value $n$" for $n=2,3,\ldots, 10^6$ may speed up things.

Assume $b>a$. Compute the Collatz sequence starting with $b$ until the first time the sequence reaches some $b'<b$.

- If $b'>a$, scratch the $b$-sequence, let $b\leftarrow b'$, and create the $b$-sequence again up to  a new $b'<b$.
- If $b'=a$, the answer is $a$, and we are done.

Otherwise, compute the sequence starting at $a$ until you reach $a'<a$.
If $b'=a'$, follow both sequences back step by step until you reach the point they meet, and we are done. 
Otherwise, let $b=\max\{a',b'\}$, $a=\min\{a',b'\}$ and restart.

---

Then again, the maximal sequence length with starting values $\le 10^6$ is 524, so simply computing the two sequences to the end and looking for the meeting point from their ends cannot take too long ...